# sql query in "WHERE IN" clause

Tags: mysql, sql

```
select * from tablename 
     where id in(select id from tablename2 where condition UNION select -1)
```

Is it ok to use select -1 as if the inner query does not result anything it will give error. It is feasible or not?

Comment: If the inner query doesn't return anything, there just won't be a row returned in the outer query. What error are you getting?

Comment: I don't think it will result in error if inner query does not return any value.

Comment: got it.. if we kept in() blank then only it gives error. if inner query returns empty query will returns empty result.Thanks anyways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won't give an error if the query returns nothing. It just returns an empty resultset.

Comment: got it.. if we kept in() blank then only it gives error. if inner query returns empty query will returns empty result.Thanks anyways

Answer (score 1):

imho, `inner-select` is far from ideal (slow)

based on your posted SQL, `an inner join` will do the trick

```
select * 
from tablename as t1
inner join tablename2 as t2
on t1.id=t2.id
where condition; --- your condition
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have to get it done with a subquery then the correct way to do it would probably be:

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename AS t1
WHERE EXISTS
    (SELECT id 
     FROM tablename2 AS t2
     WHERE conditions)
```